# ITC.apps.assetvalidation.BITCODE_IMBALANCE_ERROR.error.message

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, app-store-connect

I am having a problem submitting my iOS application to review queue. It keeps loading and throwing me error like this.

> ITC.apps.assetvalidation.BITCODE_IMBALANCE_ERROR.error.message

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: The problem is with the bitcode (**BITCODE_IMBALANCE_ERROR**) I don't know what that means (which is why this is a comment), but try re-archiving a new build and uploading it to ITC

Comment: It MIGHT mean that you have your app with Bitcode enabled but a library used by the app without it enabled. I don't know but I'd say that's a fairly decent guess. The weird part is that it says "assetvalidation". Your quote looks like the error code. What does the message say? What is the error ID?

Try exporting the archive as AppStore build and then upload the build instead. See what it says.

Comment: @Brandon no code is provided. It's just a red message on the itunes connect web page, just below the title :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid there's not much information about this issue. All  the stuff I've read about is from yesterday or today. This thread on the apple message board is what made most sense to me:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48023

It implies that there might be some issue on the Itunes Connect backend. It makes sense to me because I've already managed to do some releases on my app before, and the BITCODE flags were not changed before that. So it's either a change in the bitcode policies or some random error.

In any case, we'll probably have to wait until Apple clarifies it. I'd suggest to stay tuned to that thread on their forum :)

**EDIT: I figured it out!!**

I'm using CocoaPods, and the Pods project had the "Enable bitcode" option enabled for all targets, while my app had it disabled. That means that the frameworks were being generated with the arm64-bitcode architecture instead of the arm64-machinecode that my project requires. Putting the "Enable bitcode" to "No" for all the targets inside the Pods project does the trick.

At least, it worked for me. Too bad apple provides no feedback on this, because it looks like a recent change. I think there's another option that could work without changing the project settins: try disabling the "Include bitcode" checkbox on the Organizer, after pressing the "Upload to App Store" button.

**Edit (again)**: Disabling the "Include bitcode" checkbox in the organizer definitely works :)

Answer (score 7):

Regarding bitcode deprecation in **Xcode 14**. If you're using **fastlane** make sure to remove `include_bitcode: true` from your `build_app` call

Answer (score 6):

Use of `bitcode` is deprecated starting in Xcode 14. You can checkout the [Xcode 14 Release Notes deprecation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes).

So, we are free to remove the `uploadBitcode` key from the `exportOptionsPlist` plist file. And also make sure that your all app modules and external library's `Enable Bitcode` option in the `build Settings` should be `no`, then you will be able to upload your app to iTunes connect without getting any error or warning.